# Tensorflow: Splitting layer output into more smaller netoworks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on an image puzzler and classifier using a neural network with tensorflow.keras. The network starts with several convolutions, which will then be connected to several dense layers. Eventually I wish to split the output from a dense layer into more small dense networks, as show in the picture. I am not sure how to go a head with splitting the last dense layer into these smaller networks, as I am fairly new to machine learning. Would be great to know if anyone have any ideas or suggestions.

[image: Simple representation of the neural network I wish to implement]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split), it does exactly what you need. Example:

```
big_output = Dense(units=100)(input) # shape: [nbatch, 100]
split_tensor = tf.split(big_output, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=-1) # shape: [[nbatch, 50], [nbatch, 50]]
small_output_1 = Dense(units=10)(split_tensor[0]) # shape: [nbatch, 10]
small_output_2 = Dense(units=10)(split_tensor[1]) # shape: [nbatch, 10]
```